# Extract MAC compression (Safari extension) on a PC

Tags: windows-7, extract

I need to extract a Safari extension (.safariextz) on a PC.  There are of course [Mac OS X instructions](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/extract-code-from-safari-extensions.html) for how to do this, but none for PC.

I've tried 7zip, WinZip, and jZip...none of them recognize the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari extensions are in the `xar` (*eXtensible ARchiver*) format.

You can download the implementation source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/xar/downloads/list) and might be able to build on Windows (perhaps Cygwin).

---

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) supports `xar` archives. Change the file extension and try again.

Comment: Thanks much!  I didn't think rename extension would affect it, but that worked